# Unexpected error when running JS script in Docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

So when I run my script in my Windows terminal everything works. All the libs I use are Linux supported yet when I make my Docker Image and run it I get an error that doesn't happen on my vanilla terminal.

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received undefined

at prepareSecretKey (internal/crypto/keys.js:322:11)

at new Hmac (internal/crypto/hash.js:113:9)

at Object.createHmac (crypto.js:147:10)

at verifyPostData (/usr/src/app/bin/utils/utilFunctions.js:85:35)

at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)

at Route.dispatch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)

at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

at /usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22

at Function.process_params (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

This is happening when my script is validating the received payload. Any ideas about what could be happening?

Where key is defined:

```js
    const sig = req.get('X-Hub-Signature') || '';
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', process.env.SECRET!);
    const digest = Buffer.from(
        'sha1=' + hmac.update(payload).digest('hex'),
        'utf8'
    );
    const checksum = Buffer.from(sig, 'utf8');
}
```

Comment: where is your `key` defined?

Comment: Your env variable SECRET is probably not available inside of the container

Comment: Oh. I'll look into that.